# Проблема с Jquery, как решить?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Есть страница index.php в ней подключено jquery `(jquery-1.12.4.js)`. На этой странице есть кнопка. Нажав которую происходит загрузка содержимого другой страницы `adler.php` через `(jquery.form.js)` Все замечательно, вот только на странице `adler.php` подключено jquery той же версии. Так как на ней стоит вот этот модуль `https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html`  При загрузке этой странице идет что-то не так и модуль не грузит кнопки сохранения таблицы.   И от jquery в `index.php` и в `adler.php` отказаться не могу. Вот сам сайт

> //avia-avia.ru

и вот кнопка (Пока только для направления Москва Адлер) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот подгружаемая страница

> //avia-avia.ru/adler.php

Так вот если зайти непосредственно на `//avia-avia.ru/adler.php` то там кнопки сохранения подгружаются. Да и еще если несколько раз нажимать на кнопку показать, то таблица внутри меняет свой вид. Фантастика. Спасибо
Спасибо

Добавлю.

Вот пример кнопки.

```
$(document).ready(function(){var b="Показать";var a="Скрыть";var c="<img src='loading.gif'><b style='color:#337ab7;'>Подождите, идет загрузка...</b>";$("#form_1 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content1").html(c);$("#form_1").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_1 input").val(a);$("#content1").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content1").html("")}});$("#form_2 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content2").html(c);$("#form_2").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_2 input").val(a);$("#content2").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content2").html("")}});$("#form_3 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content3").html(c);$("#form_3").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_3 input").val(a);$("#content3").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content3").html("")}});$("#form_4 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content4").html(c);$("#form_4").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_4 input").val(a);$("#content4").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content4").html("")}});$("#form_5 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content5").html(c);$("#form_5").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_5 input").val(a);$("#content5").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content5").html("")}});$("#form_6 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content6").html(c);$("#form_6").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_6 input").val(a);$("#content6").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content6").html("")}});$("#form_7 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content7").html(c);$("#form_7").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_7 input").val(a);$("#content7").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content7").html("")}});$("#form_8 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content8").html(c);$("#form_8").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_8 input").val(a);$("#content8").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content8").html("")}});$("#form_9 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content9").html(c);$("#form_9").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_9 input").val(a);$("#content9").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content9").html("")}});$("#form_10 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content10").html(c);$("#form_10").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_10 input").val(a);$("#content10").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content10").html("")}});$("#form_11 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content11").html(c);$("#form_11").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_11 input").val(a);$("#content11").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content11").html("")}});$("#form_12 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content12").html(c);$("#form_12").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_12 input").val(a);$("#content12").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content12").html("")}});$("#form_13 input").on("click",function(d){if($(this).val()==b){$("#content13").html(c);$("#form_13").ajaxForm(function(e){$("#form_13 input").val(a);$("#content13").html(e)})}else{d.preventDefault();$(this).val(b);$("#content13").html("")}})});
```

Вызов содержимого при нажатии

```
<div class="container" style="padding:0px; margin:0 auto;text-align:center">
      <p style="font-size: 20px !important;color: grey;font-weight: normal !important;font-family: initial;">Больше авиабилетов из Москвы в Адлер</p>

<div class="div_form">
    <form method="post" action="adler.php" name="form1" id="form_1" >
    <input  type="submit" value="Показать" class="btn btn-info">
    </form>
    </div>
             <div style="clear: both"></div>
          <div class="demo" >
       <div class="table-responsive" id="content1">

      </div></div></div>
```

Вот содержимое файла adler.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>



<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting('E_ALL');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/calendar?currency=RUB&origin=MOW&destination=AER"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: ********"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($response);
echo '<table  id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th></th>';
echo '<th>Дата вылета</th>';
echo '<th>Стоимость</th>';
echo '<th>Авиакомпания</th>';
echo '<th>Дата возвращения</th>';
echo '<th>Номер рейса</th>';
echo '<th>Поиск</th>';
echo '</tr> ';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tfoot>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th></th>';
echo '<th>Дата вылета</th>';
echo '<th>Стоимость</th>';
echo '<th>Авиакомпания</th>';
echo '<th>Дата возвращения</th>';
echo '<th>Номер рейса</th>';'<th>Поиск</th>';
echo '</tr> ';
echo '</tfoot>';
echo '<tbody> ';

$price = 0;
$num = 0;
$airline = array();
foreach ($obj->data as $key => $item) {
    $num++;
    $price += $item->price;
    if(isset($airline[$item->airline])){
        $airline[$item->airline]++;
    }else{
        $airline[$item->airline] = 1;
    }
 ;
echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td></td>'; 
    echo '<td>' . date("Y/m/d", strtotime($item->departure_at)) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $item->price . '</td>'; 
    echo '<td><img alt="" src="http://pics.avs.io/100/40/' . $item->airline . '.png"></td>';   
    echo '<td>' . date("Y/m/d", strtotime("$item->return_at")) . '</td>';    
    echo '<td>' . $item->flight_number . '</td>';
   echo '<td style="    background: #004a90;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    color: #fff;"><a style="    background: #004a90;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    color: #fff;" rel="nofollow" href="http://bilety.avia-avia.ru/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=AER&depart_date=' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item->departure_at)) . '&return_date='. date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$item->return_at")) . '&marker=87111&with_request=true">Поиск</a></td></tr> ';}   echo '</tbody></table>' ;?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <style type="text/css" class="init">

    </style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/jszip.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/pdfmake.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/vfs_fonts.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
} );



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как я весь код сюда залью?

Comment: Ок сейчас подправлю.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Подправил

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Алексей Вы можете помочь? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Подгруженная страница не выполняет JS, это лишь html\css данные.
Сделайте по-другому. Пусть таблица подругужается, а когда подгрузится выполняется код по созданию из подгруженной таблицы табиличку с кнопочками.

Comment: Не могу у меня таких страничек 8 и если все будут иметь одинаковый id  $('#example')   то не загрузится вообще datatable проверял

Comment: У вас 3 варианта: 1) удалять элемент с id example перед загрузкой нового. 2) Присвоить не id а общий class 3) создать 8 id (для каждого списка по одному). Используйте то, что вам удобнее

Comment: Второй и третий не работает точно, проверял. А вот 3 каким образом можно удалить?

Comment: Должны работать, вероятно, что-то напутали. Удалить так: $("#example").remove();

Comment: Таким образом? $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );$("#example").remove();
} );

Comment: Я не понимаю каким образом сделать чтобы ""таблица подругужается, а когда подгрузится выполняется код по созданию из подгруженной таблицы табиличку с кнопочками."

Comment: Нет. Вы должны добавить это перед загрузкой данных, причем надо еще как-то проверить есть ли элемент c id example

Comment: Вот код который происходит при нажатии на кнопку где? который грузит вашу страницу? на callback успешной загрузки запхайте запуск  $('#example').DataTable(*параметры*). и не забудьте библиотеки в основной файл подключить

Comment: все в вопросе написано

Comment: именно. это были риторические вопросы. сами найдите и вставьте.